# How to change from HyperLight Load mode to forced PWM mode

Tags: voltage, current, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost

In the [MIC33M650](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MIC33M650-Data-Sheet-DS20006253A.pdf) step-down module, is there a possibility/workaround to deactivate the HyperLight Load mode? Or decrease the threshold of the current needed to activate forced-PWM mode?

Comment: The only way I see is adding a dummy load resistor.

Comment: So, its not possible to deactivate that mode or decrease the threshold of the current?

Comment: The design focus of this chip is efficiency and forced PWM would ruin this, so this option is not available. Do you have problems with output voltage ripple or emitted EMI spectrum?

Comment: Oh, thank you. I've problems with output voltage ripple.

Comment: A combination of adding a minimum load resistor and a larger output capacitor can help in some cases, but the load step response of the regulator will be affected. Check, if this is acceptable for your circuit.